# What is the spiritual significance that the Sefer Torah is in a Scroll format?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, sefer-torah

I have read the Q&A at: [Why does the Torah have to be in a scroll format](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73097/why-does-the-torah-have-to-be-in-a-scroll-format/83112?noredirect=1#comment257398_83112)

But what I am looking for in this question is something that goes beyond the purely legal and technical (halachic) reasons that it is a halacha moshe m'sinai.

It seems to me that just like the fact the the luchas are in stone, and that the letters are something that are intrinsic and not ink on gvil (and thus two independent items, liable to be separated), there is some deeper meaning to the fact that we write a Sefer Torah on gvil, and that is a continuous scroll.

Has anyone come across a deeper reason?

Comment: Scrolls were the primary way of writing things down back then. Books didn't really come around till parchment was developed and you could write on both sides

Comment: That's a deep spiritual reason? The fact that is a halacha moshe m'sinai should tell you there is something much more profound than a historical accident Would you say the same reasoning about the luchos?

Comment: Maybe the Halacha l'moshe misinai is just to counter, I don't know, writing a Torah on a bunch of pieces of tree bark held together by some rope. Just because it's brought down in Halacha doesn't mean there is such a deep significance to it.

Comment: @drysg to an extent sure! Recording covenants on duplicate stone tablets was the norm back then. That's exactly what the Israelites would have expected and understood and respected.

Comment: it's sad. Rabbi Akiva found mountains and mountains of depth in the crowns of Torah (Menachos). Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochei was able to darshan Tamei d'Mikra (Sotah). You are arguing that depth here is nothing more a superficial accident of history. (even 3rd grader could give this answer) there is something much more deeper implicit in a Halcha Moshe M'sinai (Since Torah came 2,000 years before creation). Now, I admit I don't know. I don't see any shame in anyone confessing that unless ego stands in the way of Torah.